# problem with udev rules when i want to start bash script

Tags: linux, bash, usb, udev

I am trying to write udev rules, so my usb will be recognized when plugged in,
and i want to run bash script, but seems that I have some problem,
I think I  have opened the rules file twice e.g. With vim and with a text editor. How can I fix this ?

```
$ sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/85-my_usb_device_rule.rules ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0204", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6025", RUN+="/home/supermario/workspace/bash_script.sh"
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow -- you're editing the same file twice with two different editors?  Close one, save the file with the other?

Comment: the thing is that I am editing with one editor, and i wanted to write udev rules, so I found vi/etc/udev... thats second editor..can you show me how to still write udev rules but without vi editor? and if i choose to write only in vi, than i write script in vi, and when i start vi/etc/udev... everything is ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the exact command line you provide, it seems that it will never works.

Vi doesn't take option like "add" .... 
So in fact vi is just going to edit all file provided in command line.

What you can do is : 
`sudo echo 'ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0204", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6025", RUN+="/home/supermario/workspace/bash_script.sh"' >> /etc/udev/rules.d/85-my_usb_device_rule.rules`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29071/discussion-on-answer-by-netmonk-problem-with-udev-rules-when-i-want-to-start-bas).